# Realtime outputs in android TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am going to add two integers which are given in two edit text boxes it finely calculating when i click the button "Calculate". But how can i show the result when the user entered numbers in two edit text boxes without clicking any button?

**Example:** Android 5.0 Lollipop  Calculator does this, when a user gives two number 5 (operator) 5. it generates the output without clicking <kbd>=</kbd> button

Here is my snippet

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText num1,num2;
    TextView resu;
    int res;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum2);
        resu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mynum1 = num1.getText().toString();
                String mynum2 = num2.getText().toString();

                res = Integer.parseInt(mynum1)+Integer.parseInt(mynum2);
                resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at TextWatcher in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
num1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String mynum1 = num1.getText().toString();
            String mynum2 = num2.getText().toString();

            if((mynum1!="")&&(mynum2!="")){
            res = Integer.parseInt(mynum1)+Integer.parseInt(mynum2);
            resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));}
        }
    });

num2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String mynum1 = num1.getText().toString();
            String mynum2 = num2.getText().toString();

            if((mynum1!="")&&(mynum2!="")){
            res = Integer.parseInt(mynum1)+Integer.parseInt(mynum2);
            resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));}
        }
    });
```

you can also implement textWatcher to decrease your codes